# "note" может быть равен "0": это не соответствует спецификации функции "fprintf"

Tags: c++

Написал вот такую вот програмку, вылезает предупреждение (*"note" может быть равен "0":  это не соответствует спецификации функции "fprintf".*). Подскажите как ее исправить.

```
#include <stdio.h> 
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "Russian");

    FILE* note;
    int N; //N-число точек для Rn
    float In = 0, RnMAX, RnMIN, Rn, Un;

    //Считываем данные из файла

    if ((fopen_s(&note, "input.txt", "r")) == 1)
        printf("Файл не удалось открыть\n");
    else {
        fscanf_s(note, "%f", &In);
        printf("Данные успешно считаны\n");
    }
    fclose(note);
    
    //Cчитываем значения с клавиатуры

    printf("Введите: \nMIN значение Rn => ");
    scanf_s("%f", &RnMIN);
    printf("MAX значение Rn => ");
    scanf_s("%f", &RnMAX);
    printf("N (число точек для Rn) => ");
    scanf_s("%d", &N);

    //Расчет Rn в зависимости от кол-ва N

    Rn = (RnMAX - RnMIN) / (N - 1);

    //Рассчет искомой велечины

    fopen_s(&note,"output.txt", "w");
    fprintf(note, "|Rn|Un|\n");

    for (RnMIN; RnMIN <= RnMAX; RnMIN = Rn + RnMIN)
    {
        Un = In * RnMIN;
        fprintf(note, "|%.2f|%.2f|\n", RnMIN,Un);
    };
    fclose(note);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: проверять результат fopen_s

Comment: Если не ошибаюсь, это С++, а не С

Comment: @user7860670 я проверяю в самом начале

Comment: @rendy А надо - при каждом вызове. И у других функций кстати тоже.

Comment: @user7860670 все равно не работает, может я неправильно проверяю результат?

Comment: ну первая проверка - не правильная

Comment: После `fopen_s(&note,"output.txt", "w");` должна быть еще одна проверка

Comment: Не очень понимаю - это сообщение при выполнении? При компиляции я такое не получил.

Comment: @Mikhailo да, при выполнении